# javascript is not executed inside a PHP loop unless I use die()

Tags: javascript, php

I have this simple PHP code with JS inside an if statement.

```
<?php
$x = 1;
if($x == "1"){
    echo '<script>alert("hello"); window.open("wwww.google.com","_blank");</script>';
    //die(); works if this is uncommented
}

?>
```

So I have that code above and the weird thing is that the JS part is only executed when I use die inside the if statement which I don't want to do as the page doesn't end with only that if statement and there a bunch of other stuff happening below. So I was wondering why this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: probably because the bunch of other stuff happening below.

Comment: IMO, issue is with some other code which is not shared..

Comment: You can try to use `flush()` command to flush output buffer, it should work regardless of the other code below.

Comment: PHP execute first and then javascript. Javascript part will only execute once your PHP execution has been completed. So here you have infinite loop that's why javascript is not executing.

Comment: Paste the full code. This should work unless you have something blocking this execution below, or above.

Comment: @RahulPatel if that is the case then how do I go around that problem? Also, I already commented  the other codes and just left this part and still problem exists, I will now try the answer provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `die();` to print final JavaScript directly, so store all JS as string variable then `die('<script>.....</script>');`, and every thing should works fine.

```
<?php
$x = 1;
if($x == "1"){
$script = "<script>
                var hello = 'Hello';
                hello += ' Sir'; ";
$script .= "alert(hello);</script>";
    die($script);
}

?>
```

Now output is

```
        <script>
        var hello = 'Hello';
        hello += ' Sir';
        alert(hello);
        </script>
```

Example with for loops

```
<?php
$x = 1;
if($x == "1"){
    $script = "<script>
                var hello = 'Hello';
                hello += ' Sir'; ";
    $script .= "alert(hello);
                </script>";


    $script .= "<script>";
    for($i = 0; $i<5;$i++){
        $script .= "console.log(".$i.");";
    }
    $script .= "</script>";
    die($script);
}

?>
```

**Update:**  another way using `return` inside a `function`:

```
<?php
function echoScript(){
$x = 1;
if($x == "1"){
$script = "<script>
                var hello = 'Hello';
                hello += ' Sir'; ";
$script .= "alert(hello);</script>";
    echo $script;
return;
//so all other scripts inside this function not excuted
}
echo "this shouldn't displayed because function has return";
//and all after won't work
//...... 

}//end of function echoScript()


//call function
echoScript();
?>
```

Comment: Is there anyway for this to work without using die? As I want the page to proceed loading after executing the script.

Comment: you mean that you have some code after die(), so why do you use die() use echo instead ?Do you want to stop script in that line then continue after some lines?

Comment: I just tried using die to see if it gets inside my if statement, and it did and that was the only time my JS worked, so I guess what Rahul said is true that JS is only executed after the PHP. Yeah I was hoping to use JS here to open a new tab but I'm looking now if there is a PHP option for that

Comment: That's right PHP code will done from server side then JavaScript do the task in client side.